# Discontinuous Differentiable and One to One

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

If the derivative of a function (from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) at a point $x_0$ is discontinuous, does that imply that the function is not one to one or injective in a neighborhood of $x_0$?

If not, how does one go in showing that the function is not injective at $x_0$ given that the derivative of the function is discontinuous at $x_0$.

My thoughts: Since the function's derivative is not always positive or negative, then the function is not injective because it is neither always decreasing or always increasing. Does that sound right?

Comment: Why is the function's derivative not always positive or negative?

Comment: So I thought about it. There exist three cases, one if the function is positive or negative, one where the function is more positive and one where the function is more negative. In all three cases, $f$ can be mapped to multiple values to the different derivative values.

Comment: @mvw - that's an unlikely assumption, because OP's problem is strictly local (so we're only concerned with the function's behaviour near some point) while your assumption is global

Comment: doesn't matter if it's $f$ or $f'$, the point is still valid. $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ only means that it's a scalar function of one variable

Answer (score 10):

No, such a function can still be one-to-one in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

To see this, start with the usual example of a differentiable function with discontinuous derivative, i.e. $f(0) := 0$ and

$$
f(x) := x^2 \cdot \sin(1/x) \text{ for } x\neq 0 .
$$

It is not hard to see that $f$ has derivative $0$ at $0$. Away from the origin, the derivative is given by

$$
f'(x) = 2x \cdot \sin(1/x) + x^2 \cdot \cos(1/x) \cdot (-1/x^2) = 2x \cdot \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x).
$$

Observe that **$f'$ is bounded on every bounded set**, in particular on $(-1,1)$ (for example $|f'(x)| \leq 3$ on this interval).

Hence, if we set $g(x) := 1000 \cdot x + f(x)$, then $g'(x) = 1000 + f'(x) > 0$ on $(-1,1)$, so that $g$ is one-to-one on $(-1,1)$, but $g'$ is not continuous at $0$ (otherwise $f' = g' - 1000$ would be continuous).

EDIT: By modifying this example (truncate $f$ smoothly to have compact support), one can even construct such a function with the property that $g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ is a bijection (homeomorphism).